# How can I transfer Pokémon from Pokémon Sun to Pokémon X?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-sun-moon, pokemon-bank

I downloaded Pokébank and I was able to transfer Pokémon from X to Sun but I can't transfer Pokémon from Sun to X. How do I trade from Sun back to X?

Answer (score 5):

You simply can't transfer Pokémon from Sun/Moon to X/Y.

Comment: Affirmative. I was going to say the exact same thing.

Comment: To elaborate on @DanmakuGrazer's answer, the reason is that some pokemon featured in Sun didn't exist in X, and the game couldn't be able to recognize. Therefore, X was made to not trade with Sun so Sun-debuted pokemon couldn't go onto X (if a Sun-debuted pokemon got onto X, it wouldn't recognize it, making a glitch pokemon. It may have the same stats, but any Sun moves/abilities or the pokemon itself wouldn't work correctly. Also, it wouldn't actually display itself during battle.l, probably display a default pokemon or crash the game when it went into battle).

Comment: @TheMattbat999 That's a lot of speculation there. The game doesn't allow tradebacks for any Pokémon, not just those from generation 7.

Comment: I was just explaining this situation. I know about not able to trade backwards..

Comment: @TheMattbat999 - You can trade pokemon caught in ORAS back to XY through pokebank. The only condition is that they didn't know any new ORAS-exclusive moves. There's no technical reason why they couldn't do something similar for gen 7 -> gen 6 and just prevent new things from being transferred. Banning all backwards transfers was a formal decision on Game Freak's part.

Comment: @Pyritie XY and ORAS are both gen 6, there wasn't big technical changes on the game as in ORAS to SM. Take in consideration that stuff like z-moves, rising IVs using silver and gold caps (and maybe other stuff like some of the new habilities) most probably imply a huge modification in the way the pokemon data is stored making SM data incompatible with older versions.

Comment: @Grirg They aren't -- the save data structure from gen 6 to 7 is mostly unchanged. And if pokebank can convert a gen 6 data structure to a gen 7 one, there's zero reason why it can't go backwards. The gen 6 data structure contains enough "extra space" to fill with new information like hyper training.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The only backwards compatible Pokémon games are those from Generation II (Gold, Silver and Crystal) via Time Capsule. From Generation III onwards Pokémon games are forwards compatible, but not backwards compatible. You can transfer Pokémon forth, but not back.